# camel calling to rest service, body is empty

Tags: apache-camel

My camel project receives an url, it acts as a proxy and sends a GET petition to a rest service with a route definition like this:

```
rest("/car")
  .get("/{id}")
  .param().name("id").type(RestParamType.path)
  .dataType("int").endParam()
  .to("http://0.0.0.0:8081?bridgeEndpoint=true")
  .consumes("application/json")
  .to("direct:jsoncar");

from("direct:jsoncar")
  .streamCaching()
  .log("log:${body}")
  .process(new Processor() { 
     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
        String data = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class); 
        ...
        ...
     }
});
```

The rest service sends back a json in a stream. The problem is that body is always empty. I have tried it in many ways:

```
from("direct:jsoncar")
  .streamCaching()
  .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE,constant("text/json"))
  .marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson, true)
  .process(new Processor() {
     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
       String dto = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
       ...
     });
```

But it is always empty.
Please, any body has any idea of the nature of the problem?